# Using Group By on Date Column in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have large historical data and I want to group by it month. I am preparing below query on HP Vertica database to get my data grouped by Month.

```
SELECT 
      Region, Country,
      TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(Order_Date,'m/yyyy'),'m/yyyy') as MONTH_Order_Date, 
      SUM(CAST(Unit_Price as NUMERIC(37,15))) as Sum_Unit_Price, 
      SUM(CAST(Total_Revenue as NUMERIC(37,15))) as Sum_Total_Revenue 
FROM SalesRecords 
GROUP BY Region,Country,TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(Order_Date,'m/yyyy'),'m/yyyy')
ORDER BY Region ASC,Country ASC,TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(Order_Date,'m/yyyy'),'m/yyyy') ASC
```

Now problem with this query is performance, over 1 billion data it is taking almost 2 minute and return record set after group by is 0.1 million rows.
I need data in below shown format and due to that I need to parse date at DB level to get formatted date and this formatting taking time on DB server.

Please suggest me any other way which I can use because on same table if I am grouping data on some other column except the date type column performance is good, returned record set almost in 40 second over 1 billion record.

I need to do this performance for all major RDBMS.

```
Region  Country     MONTH_Order_Date    Sum_Unit_Price          Sum_Total_Revenue
Asia    Bangladesh  2010-01-01 00:00:00 186252.349999999999937  920607119.140000001169023
Asia    Bangladesh  2011-01-01 00:00:00 186456.190000000000641  931633189.440000000452752
Asia    Bangladesh  2012-01-01 00:00:00 194925.550000000000312  969718040.969999998663069
Asia    Bangladesh  2013-01-01 00:00:00 194048.289999999999566  1017253078.219999998891571
Asia    Bangladesh  2014-01-01 00:00:00 184143.090000000000413  915867255.449999996567606
Asia    Bangladesh  2015-01-01 00:00:00 193697.769999999999864  959097995.869999999053554
Asia    Bangladesh  2016-01-01 00:00:00 184833.730000000000529  955360230.500000001682568
Asia    Bangladesh  2017-01-01 00:00:00 111476.840000000000014  563824376.189999998257226
Asia    Bhutan      2010-01-01 00:00:00 186506.900000000000474  916963415.479999997623498
```

Comment: You may try add additional column with calculated value from the formula "TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(Order_Date,'m/yyyy'),'m/yyyy')" and update it every time you update or insert the data. Use this new column in group by and order by clauses. Also add index on this column. Should be faster.

Comment: Maybe `date_trunc('month', Order_Date)` is faster?

Comment: If we're talking about performance we need, at least, the explain plan of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Vertica run-length encoding (RLE) allows you to leverage low-cardinality columns for improved query performance and disk space savings, and converting a very granular data type like timestamp to mmyyyy might be perfect for the job.

1) Put the mmyyyy conversion into your data load process

2) create a new projection with a new computed column called month_year and formatted mmyyyy.

3) In the projection column list and in the projection ORDER BY, put this and other low-card columns at the beginning of the list. High-card columns go towards the end of the list. But any high-card join columns (like the key) should be immediately after the low-card columns.

4) Be sure to specify ENCODING_RLE on this and all other low-card columns.

These two links to Vertica docs explain the concepts involved:

[Choosing Sort Order: Best Practices](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/PhysicalSchema/ChoosingSortOrderBestPractices.htm)

[Optimizing Queries for Projections with Predicates](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/Optimizations/OptimizingProjectionsForQueriesWithPredicates.htm%3FTocPath%3DProgrammer's%2520Guide%7COptimizing%2520Query%2520Perform)

Answer (score 0):

For grouping by year or month you can use :

`GROUP BY YEAR(Order_Date)` or `MONTH(Order_Date)`

But again your data is too large for us to try and test it on our end ,only you can do the actual math it takes to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this - each change speeds up a bit, and the sum of it all might lead to a good final result:

```
    SELECT
        Region
      , Country
      , YEAR(order_date)*100+month(order_date)   AS yearmonth
      -- extracting integers from dates is faster than TO_CHAR()
      -- and the result is INTEGER - the fastest type to GROUP BY ...
      , CAST(SUM(Unit_Price   ) AS NUMERIC(37, 15)) AS Sum_Unit_Price
      , CAST(SUM(Total_Revenue) AS NUMERIC(37, 15)) AS Sum_Total_Revenue
      -- instead of CAST-ing each input value, CAST the final grouping
      -- result once
    FROM SalesRecords
    GROUP BY 1,2,3 -- sometimes the optimizer is clever enough - 
    ORDER BY 1,2,3 -- but this ensures no repeated expression evaluation
    ;
```

Good luck

Marco